# Searching in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

My web application has users and Coworker relationship. I want to search users which has Coworker relationship with specific user. I used this query:

```
var query = _client
                .Cypher
                .Start(new
                           {
                               //user = Node.ByIndexLookup(IndexHelper.USER_INDEX, "Email", email)

                           }
                ).Match(String.Format("user-[:{0}]-(coworkers)", CoWorker.TypeKey))                
                .Where((User coworkers) => coworkers.Email.Contains(term))
                .Return<Node<User>>("coworkers");
```

But It throws invalid parameter at

`Where((User coworkers) => coworkers.Email.Contains(term))`.

How can I replace this condition to search coworker with term? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Cypher doesn't actually support a contains operator like this, hence why the exception says there is no .NET equivalent.

The nearest you could do is use a regex:

```
WHERE coworkers.Email =~ ".*something.*"
```

But that would be horribly inefficient because you would run a regex across every node.